# Eudora crashes under Snow Leopard when checking mail

Tags: snow-leopard, rosetta

I have a weird Eudora problem that I don't even know quite where to start to solve. I have three Intel Macs, (a MacBook, a Mac Air and a MacBook Pro) all running the latest update of 10.6.8 (including the most recent v.1.1 of the security update.) Eudora 6.2.4 (the last version released) runs flawlessly on two of the machines and crashes consistently when checking mail on the third machine.

I'm at a loss as to how to begin to troubleshoot this issue.  Any suggestions?  Of course a real solution would also be welcome.

Here in all its glory is the crash report:

```
Process:         Eudora [3269]
Path:            /Applications/Eudora Application Folder/Eudora.app/Contents/MacOS/Eudora
Identifier:      com.qualcomm.eudora
Version:         6.2.4 (6.2.4)
Code Type:       PPC (Translated)
Parent Process:  launchd [104]

Date/Time:       2012-02-07 20:48:56.463 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  10

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815aa8b spin_lock_wrapper + 89587
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb818c3eb CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 173427
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb818eeec CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 184436
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80e88cb 0xb8000000 + 952523
4   ???                             0x8aacca76 0 + 2326579830

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x80142afa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x80143267 mach_msg + 68
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb819440f CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 206231
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x80170259 _pthread_start + 345
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x801700de thread_start + 34

Thread 2:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815acc0 spin_lock_wrapper + 90152
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8179c5b CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 97763
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145397 spin_lock_wrapper + 1791
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 3:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815a8ff spin_lock_wrapper + 89191
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8176e5d CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 85989
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145397 spin_lock_wrapper + 1791
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 4:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815a8ff spin_lock_wrapper + 89191
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8176e5d CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 85989
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145397 spin_lock_wrapper + 1791
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 5:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815abd0 spin_lock_wrapper + 89912
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8170340 CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 58568
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145c1d spin_lock_wrapper + 3973
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 6:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815ad03 spin_lock_wrapper + 90219
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb81749fb CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 76675
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145c1d spin_lock_wrapper + 3973
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 7:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815a93a spin_lock_wrapper + 89250
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8176f67 CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 86255
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145c1d spin_lock_wrapper + 3973
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 8:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815ad03 spin_lock_wrapper + 90219
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb81749fb CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 76675
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145c1d spin_lock_wrapper + 3973
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 9:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815a8ff spin_lock_wrapper + 89191
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8176e5d CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 85989
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c6b13 0xb8000000 + 813843
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
5   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145c1d spin_lock_wrapper + 3973
6   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 10 Crashed:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c5d10 0xb8000000 + 810256
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80c0037 0xb8000000 + 786487
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80dd8e8 0xb8000000 + 907496
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb8145397 spin_lock_wrapper + 1791
4   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb801ceb7 0xb8000000 + 118455

Thread 11:
0   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb815aa8b spin_lock_wrapper + 89587
1   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb818c3eb CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 173427
2   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb818eeec CallPPCFunctionAtAddressInt + 184436
3   LaunchCFMApp                    0xb80e88cb 0xb8000000 + 952523
4   ???                             0x8aacca76 0 + 2326579830

Thread 10 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0xb80c5ce8  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x0000000c
  edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x80a17390  ebp: 0xb0428e38  esp: 0xb0428e00
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0xb80c5d10   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x80000000 - 0x8005dff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x8007d000 - 0x800e7fe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x80142000 - 0x802e9ff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x8036b000 - 0x804e6fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x805de000 - 0x805ecfe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <3CE8AA79-F077-F1B0-A039-9103A4A02E92> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x805f1000 - 0x805fdff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x80601000 - 0x80647ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x80654000 - 0x807d6fe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <D5980817-6D19-9636-51C3-E82BAE26776B> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x80838000 - 0x808e5fe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x808f9000 - 0x808fcfe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???) <A4F6ADCC-6448-37B4-ED6C-ABB2CD06F448> /usr/lib/dyld
0xb8000000 - 0xb81defff  LaunchCFMApp ??? (???) <6437A74D-607F-7339-5F7E-F6B0EF81C25D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Translated Code Information:
objc[3269]: garbage collection is ON
Rosetta Version:  22.27
Args:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp /Applications/Eudora Application Folder/Eudora.app/Contents/MacOS/Eudora 
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (0x0001)

Thread 0: (0xb019ed74, 0xb815a8ff)
0x96785aa4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 248 
0x96784190: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_worker_thread + 116 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x20000000      lr: 0x96785abc     ctr: 0x96601600
r00: 0xffffffda     r01: 0xf0182dc0     r02: 0x00000000     r03: 0x00002903     
r04: 0x00000040     r05: 0x3b9aaf93     r06: 0x00000020     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x3b9aaf93     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3b9aaf93     r11: 0xa09da698     
r12: 0x96601600     r13: 0x00000000     r14: 0x00000000     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x00000000     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x00000000     r19: 0x00000000     
r20: 0x00000000     r21: 0xa09e07cc     r22: 0xa09e07c0     r23: 0xa09e07c8     
r24: 0x00009eda     r25: 0xe221007b     r26: 0xa09e050c     r27: 0x00000040     
r28: 0x0000000f     r29: 0x224d2f93     r30: 0xa09e07a0     r31: 0x967859b4     

Thread 1: Crashed (0xb0428e00, 0xb80c5d10)
0x7f5b95f0: No symbol
0x7f5b8d80: No symbol
0x7f53a4f0: No symbol
0x7f556f70: No symbol
0x7f4f1f00: No symbol
0x7f4f1114: No symbol
0x7f454c88: No symbol
0x7f4525fc: No symbol
0x7f451ff0: No symbol
0x7f55e6fc: No symbol
0x97843ed4: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _CooperativeThread + 348 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x20000000      lr: 0x7f5b961c     ctr: 0x966ebdf4
r00: 0x00000001     r01: 0xf0509500     r02: 0x0182ae00     r03: 0x01831d60     
r04: 0x01828954     r05: 0x01831d68     r06: 0x01831e08     r07: 0x20efc098     
r08: 0x00000a30     r09: 0x019f3000     r10: 0xfffffff7     r11: 0x24000042     
r12: 0x00000000     r13: 0x018304a9     r14: 0x01830482     r15: 0x00000001     
r16: 0x00000001     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x0199da94     r19: 0xf0509cd4     
r20: 0x00000001     r21: 0x00000000     r22: 0x00000000     r23: 0x00000000     
r24: 0x018304b0     r25: 0x0182f638     r26: 0xf0509b20     r27: 0xf0509640     
r28: 0x000003e3     r29: 0x019fa400     r30: 0x005cf2f0     r31: 0x01831d60     

Thread 2: (0xb02a2d44, 0xb815ad03)
0x9669e6a4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_cond_wait + 880 
0x17226df0: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenTransport.framework/Versions/A/OpenTransport : _CarbonOperationThreadFunc + 172 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x9669e810     ctr: 0x966ebdf4
r00: 0x0000014e     r01: 0xf0284aa0     r02: 0xf0284aec     r03: 0x00006903     
r04: 0x00006a03     r05: 0x00000000     r06: 0x00000000     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x00000000     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x96619694     r11: 0xa09da1b0     
r12: 0x966ebdf4     r13: 0xf0284bb4     r14: 0xf0284bb0     r15: 0xf0284bac     
r16: 0xf0284ba8     r17: 0xf0284ba4     r18: 0xf0284ba0     r19: 0xf0284d08     
r20: 0xf0284b8c     r21: 0x172400c0     r22: 0x00000000     r23: 0x00000000     
r24: 0x00000000     r25: 0x00000000     r26: 0xa09e171c     r27: 0x00000000     
r28: 0x00557d30     r29: 0x0190f400     r30: 0x005578f8     r31: 0x9669e340     

Thread 3: (0xb04aad44, 0xb815ad03)
0x9669e6a4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_cond_wait + 880 
0x17233854: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenTransport.framework/Versions/A/OpenTransport : _CarbonInetOperThreadFunc + 208 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x9669e810     ctr: 0x966ebdf4
r00: 0x0000014e     r01: 0xf0484d50     r02: 0xf0484d9c     r03: 0x00006f03     
r04: 0x00006c03     r05: 0x00000000     r06: 0x00000000     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x00000000     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x96619694     r11: 0xa09da1b0     
r12: 0x966ebdf4     r13: 0xf0486e5c     r14: 0xf0484e6c     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x7072756e     r17: 0xf0484e5c     r18: 0xf0484e50     r19: 0xf0484e4c     
r20: 0xf0484e48     r21: 0xf0484e40     r22: 0x00000000     r23: 0x00000000     
r24: 0x00000000     r25: 0x00000000     r26: 0xa09e171c     r27: 0x00000000     
r28: 0x001039f0     r29: 0x00803a00     r30: 0x001029d8     r31: 0x9669e340     

Thread 4: (0xb0220d78, 0xb815abd0)
0x172250cc: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenTransport.framework/Versions/A/OpenTransport : _BSD_watchevent + 44 
0x1722a788: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenTransport.framework/Versions/A/OpenTransport : _CarbonSelectThreadFunc + 228 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x17225060     ctr: 0x966432a0
r00: 0x00000000     r01: 0xf0203d50     r02: 0x1723bf18     r03: 0x000000e8     
r04: 0xf0203e08     r05: 0x00000000     r06: 0x00000000     r07: 0x01000000     
r08: 0x1723cb08     r09: 0x434f4e44     r10: 0xffffffff     r11: 0x1723f1a0     
r12: 0x966432a0     r13: 0x1723a6b4     r14: 0xf0203e24     r15: 0xf0203e5f     
r16: 0xf0203e50     r17: 0xf0203e4c     r18: 0xf0203e54     r19: 0x70636c73     
r20: 0xf0203e08     r21: 0x0fffffff     r22: 0x00000000     r23: 0x172400c0     
r24: 0x00000000     r25: 0x1724a6b4     r26: 0x00000000     r27: 0xf0203e58     
r28: 0xf0203e08     r29: 0x00000000     r30: 0x00000000     r31: 0x1722a6b4     

Thread 5: (0xb009ad38, 0xb815acc0)
0x967844b8: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228 
0x96783e9c: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_queue_invoke + 308 
0x9678402c: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_worker_thread2 + 372 
0x96784168: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_worker_thread + 76 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x20000000      lr: 0x96784480     ctr: 0x966452d8
r00: 0x0000016b     r01: 0xf0080bb0     r02: 0x00000000     r03: 0x00000004     
r04: 0x00000000     r05: 0x00000000     r06: 0xf0080d0c     r07: 0x00000001     
r08: 0xf0080d28     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000039     r11: 0xa09d9530     
r12: 0x966452d8     r13: 0x10624dd3     r14: 0x967d3b04     r15: 0xf0080c0c     
r16: 0xf0080c8c     r17: 0xa09f43dc     r18: 0xf0080d28     r19: 0xa09ee588     
r20: 0xa09ef588     r21: 0xf0080d0c     r22: 0xa09ee508     r23: 0xa09ee488     
r24: 0xa09f43dc     r25: 0x00000000     r26: 0xa09e062c     r27: 0x00000000     
r28: 0xa09e0604     r29: 0xa09e033c     r30: 0xf0080d28     r31: 0x967843dc     

Thread 6: (0xb0324d70, 0xb815a93a)
0x9669e6a4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_cond_wait + 880 
0x97844984: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 240 
0x97846a00: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 468 
0x977d4670: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : AsyncFileThread(void*) + 92 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x9669e6e8     ctr: 0x96601610
r00: 0xffffffd9     r01: 0xf03058b0     r02: 0x00000001     r03: 0x00006b03     
r04: 0x00006e03     r05: 0x0000003c     r06: 0x00000000     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x20e18f10     r09: 0x00000001     r10: 0xf0305e88     r11: 0xa09da6a0     
r12: 0x96601610     r13: 0x00000000     r14: 0x00000000     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x00000000     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x978b51cc     r19: 0x978b51d0     
r20: 0xa09e16d0     r21: 0x978b51d4     r22: 0x00000000     r23: 0x00000000     
r24: 0x0000003c     r25: 0x00000001     r26: 0xa09e171c     r27: 0xf0305e88     
r28: 0xa0ca54ac     r29: 0x00000000     r30: 0xa0ca54e0     r31: 0x9669e340     

Thread 7: (0xb03a6d74, 0xb815a8ff)
0x96785aa4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 248 
0x96784190: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_worker_thread + 116 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x20000000      lr: 0x96785abc     ctr: 0x96601600
r00: 0xffffffda     r01: 0xf0386dc0     r02: 0x00000000     r03: 0x00002603     
r04: 0x00000040     r05: 0x3b9ab15b     r06: 0x00000020     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x3b9ab15b     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3b9ab15b     r11: 0xa09da698     
r12: 0x96601600     r13: 0x00000000     r14: 0x00000000     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x00000000     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x00000000     r19: 0x00000000     
r20: 0x00000000     r21: 0xa09e070c     r22: 0xa09e0700     r23: 0xa09e0708     
r24: 0x00009edb     r25: 0x78237434     r26: 0xa09e0398     r27: 0x00000040     
r28: 0x0000000f     r29: 0x224d315b     r30: 0xa09e06e0     r31: 0x967859b4     

Thread 8: (0xb7fff41c, 0xb815aa8b)
0x005a1250: No symbol
0x97843570: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _YieldToThread + 524 
0x97843610: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _YieldToAnyThread + 20 
0x7f55f578: No symbol
0x7f45c6c0: No symbol
0x7f45c260: No symbol
0x7f4571bc: No symbol
0x7f5bd6c8: No symbol

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x96601cc4     ctr: 0x96601590
r00: 0xffffffe1     r01: 0xbfffefc0     r02: 0x00000013     r03: 0xbffff07c     
r04: 0x00000003     r05: 0x00000018     r06: 0x00000020     r07: 0x00004403     
r08: 0x00000000     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x977fd9ac     r11: 0xa09da194     
r12: 0x96601590     r13: 0x0182f5de     r14: 0x0182f598     r15: 0x00000002     
r16: 0x0182f630     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x0182fab8     r19: 0x0182f548     
r20: 0x0182f54c     r21: 0x0182f54f     r22: 0xbffff07c     r23: 0x00000018     
r24: 0x00000020     r25: 0x00004403     r26: 0x00000000     r27: 0x00000000     
r28: 0x00000003     r29: 0x00000003     r30: 0x00000000     r31: 0x9784336c     

Thread 9: (0xb074284c, 0xb815aa8b)
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 
0x97843e30: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore : _CooperativeThread + 184 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x00000000      lr: 0x96601cc4     ctr: 0x96601590
r00: 0xffffffe1     r01: 0xf058adc0     r02: 0x00000000     r03: 0xf058ae7c     
r04: 0x00000002     r05: 0x00000000     r06: 0x00000020     r07: 0x00009203     
r08: 0x00000000     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0xa09efc88     r11: 0xa09da194     
r12: 0x96601590     r13: 0x00000000     r14: 0x00000000     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x00000000     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x00000000     r19: 0x00000000     
r20: 0x00000000     r21: 0x00000000     r22: 0xf058ae7c     r23: 0x00000000     
r24: 0x00000020     r25: 0x00009203     r26: 0x00000000     r27: 0x00000000     
r28: 0x00000002     r29: 0x00000002     r30: 0x20e0b170     r31: 0x97843d80     

Thread 10: (0xb011cd74, 0xb815a8ff)
0x96785aa4: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 248 
0x96784190: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __dispatch_worker_thread + 116 
0x966a1f08: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib : __pthread_body + 40 
0x00000000: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Support/LaunchCFMApp :   + 0 

PPC Thread State
srr0: 0x00000000    srr1: 0x00000000                     vrsave: 0x00000000
cr:  0xXXXXXXXX     xer: 0x20000000      lr: 0x96785abc     ctr: 0x96601600
r00: 0xffffffda     r01: 0xf0101dc0     r02: 0x00000000     r03: 0x00002903     
r04: 0x00000040     r05: 0x3b9aadde     r06: 0x00000020     r07: 0x00000000     
r08: 0x3b9aadde     r09: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3b9aadde     r11: 0xa09da698     
r12: 0x96601600     r13: 0x00000000     r14: 0x00000000     r15: 0x00000000     
r16: 0x00000000     r17: 0x00000000     r18: 0x00000000     r19: 0x00000000     
r20: 0x00000000     r21: 0xa09e07cc     r22: 0xa09e07c0     r23: 0xa09e07c8     
r24: 0x00009edb     r25: 0xa8133661     r26: 0xa09e050c     r27: 0x00000040     
r28: 0x0000000f     r29: 0x224d2dde     r30: 0xa09e07a0     r31: 0x967859b4
```

Comment: Could you include a full crash log in your question? Just be aware that it is rare but not impossible that the crash log will indicate the problem to someone reading your question.

Comment: Do you have something called Application Enhancer installed? A thread I found on macworld.com indicates that you should add Eudora to the Application Enhancer Master Exclude List, if you have it.

Comment: (I looked at the crash log and I don't recognize the problem or know how to solve it.) Could you also open /Applications/Utilities/Console.app, try to launch Eudora again, and add any new log entries (by time/datestamp) to your original question?

Comment: I don't have Application Enhancer installed. When I relaunch Eudora and try to check mail, I get only the identical log that I just posted (modulo the date and PID).  No other messages appear in the console associated with that event.

Comment: Alright. I'm running out of ideas, so I think you should follow up with Eudora support: http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/

Comment: @bneely You do realize that Eudora hasn't been supported since 2007, right?  So unfortunately the support site is more of an archeological site. :-)

Comment: Now I do! I only use Mail and gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [an article](http://forums.macresource.com/read.php?1,1310954) that states Security Update 2012-001 causes problems for Rosetta applications. (You're using Rosetta to run a PPC application on an Intel Mac.) Apple apparently released version 1.1 of the security update 2012-001, on Feb 3 2012. Run Software Update (it's available in the Apple menu) and see if that update is offered to you.

Comment: I had already installed that update when I posted the question, so this must be something else.